# TextView flow around another TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have custom list item layout as shown at the image.
Is it possible, that "bold textview" will flow around "price textview", and "small font textview" will wrap text to second line if text will be too long(and will possibly overlay "price textview")?

Thanks a lot

[image]

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:padding="3dip"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
              android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/product_dummy"
            android:contentDescription="@string/list_image_desc"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"

        android:text="product name"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
        android:gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="100€"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textColor="#6bc920"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/product_form"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/product_name"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/product_price"
        android:text="product form"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/product_name"
        />
```

Comment: Not sure that there is a way as suggested already.  Tried playing around with it for a while to see if I could get it to wrap, but it doesn't look as though it is designed to handle this kind of layout in the standard layout resources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way of doing this with the TextView. I'd suggest you use a WebView instead and float the price on the right using standard html/css techniques.

Comment: Thanks for advice. And what about performance of webview compared to textview in listview with many items(each with my design)?